# PHP how to replace a certain thing in string?

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to create a tooltip related to world of warcraft.

Some descriptions have

```
|TInterface\ICONS\inv_offhand_1h_ulduarraid_d_01:24:24:1.75:1.75|t Rest of description
```

how can I change this string into

```
<img src='images/interface/icons/inv_offhand_1h_ulduarraid_d_01.png' width='24' height='24'> Rest of description
```

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Why have your attempts to do this yourself failed?

Comment: I didn't know where to start, still learning php!

Comment: If you're still learning, the best way to learn is by attempt. Read the documentation and see what you can figure out on your own. Then, if you're still stuck, come to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 100% sure the string will be in the same format you can do it like the following.

```
<?php
$string = '|TInterface\ICONS\inv_offhand_1h_ulduarraid_d_01:24:24:1.75:1.75|t Rest of description';

$part = explode('|', $string);
list($url, $width, $height) = explode(':', $part[1]);

$description = substr($part[2], 2);
$url = substr(strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $url)), 1);

echo '<img src="images/'.$url.'.png" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"> '.$description;
```

https://3v4l.org/H9Lum

Result:

```
<img src="images/interface/icons/inv_offhand_1h_ulduarraid_d_01.png" width="24" height="24"> Rest of description
```

Comment: No probs, it should work fine, but may need tweaking abit if case changes e.g: `inv_offhand_1h_ulduarraid_d_01` becomes `inv_Offhand_1H_ulduarraid_d_01` etc